# Pass state value as props react native

Tags: react-native, redux, react-hooks, state, react-props

I am trying to make a reusable text input component, but I want to grab the value that the user types to manipulate it on the App.js

TextInputComponent.js

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, TextInput } from 'react-native'

const TextInputComponent = (props) => {
  const [text, onChangeText] = useState("")

    return (
    <View>
      <TextInput style={styles.container} value={text} onChangeText={onChangeText} placeholder="Enter"/>
    </View>
    )
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      height: 50,
      width: 200,
      padding: 10,
      margin: 10,
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor: "black",
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
    },
  });
  

export default TextInputComponent
```

App.js

```js
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View } from 'react-native';
import TextInputComponent from './src/components/TextInputComponent';

export default function App() {

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row' }}>
    <Text>Test</Text>
    <TextInputComponent/>
    <Button title="A" onPress={()=> console.log(-------> text value from TextInputComponent <-----)}></Button>
    </View>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

In order to access the state value created on the TextInputComponent.js what do I need to do?

Comment: You have to go to https://reactjs.org/ and read about props. You're calling props in the component argument and you're not using them. This is not basic react, it's essential react, and if you don't know how to do this, I suggest some youtube tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is to pass a custom method through to the component and then use it as the onChangeText method:

```
const TextInputComponent = ({ customMethod }) => {
  const [text, onChangeText] = useState("")

    return (
      <View>
        <TextInput style={styles.container} value={text} onChangeText={(txt) => customMethod(txt)} placeholder="Enter"/>
      </View>
    )
}
```

Then in App.js you have the method:

```
customMethod = (txt) => {
    // do something with txt variable
}
```

and:

```
<TextInputComponent customMethod={customMethod} />
```

Might require some tweaking to get it to work (I didn't test it), but that's the general idea.